# Does type 14=page fault kernel panic mean that RAM is bad?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

A few days ago I upgraded my mac book pro to 16GB of RAM and now I am getting some kernel panics with page faults. Are page fault kernel panics typically caused by bad RAM or could there be another cause? I did run the Apple hardware tests after I installed the RAM and it did not find anything wrong with the RAM.

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  141599 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    D03F6660-A40C-3C34-B30E-A75DDB085DC5

Tue Nov  5 08:43:29 2013
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff8026ab8945): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8026a87f0c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000032000028, CR3: 0x00000002a688b070, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000001, RBX: 0x0000000032000000, RCX: 0xffffff804b3a1920, RDX: 0x0000000000000821
RSP: 0xffffff81f70dbd70, RBP: 0xffffff81f70dbd90, RSI: 0x000000002540be40, RDI: 0xffffff802b1bd500
R8:  0xffffff81f70dbee0, R9:  0xffffff81f70dbed0, R10: 0x00007fff8803f000, R11: 0x00007fff612f8064
R12: 0xffffff802b1bd500, R13: 0xffffff805f1da5e0, R14: 0xffffff805f1da5e0, R15: 0x0000000000008000
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff8026a87f0c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000032000028, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x6

acktrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f70dba10 : 0xffffff8026a1d636 
0xffffff81f70dba80 : 0xffffff8026ab8945 
0xffffff81f70dbc50 : 0xffffff8026acebfd 
0xffffff81f70dbc70 : 0xffffff8026a87f0c 
0xffffff81f70dbd90 : 0xffffff8026a62dcb 
0xffffff81f70dbf20 : 0xffffff8026ab8d90 
0xffffff81f70dbfb0 : 0xffffff8026aceb24 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: findNames

Mac OS version:
12F45

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: EA38B02E-2B88-309F-BA68-1DE29F605DD8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000026800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8026a00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,3 (Mac-942459F5819B171B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 147419616197268
last loaded kext at 22944437105525: com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.8 (addr 0xffffff7fa844b000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 153513961626: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   621.4.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa73bf000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.techsmith.TACC  1.0.2
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboardUSB   8.2
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboard  8.2
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.8
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 10.0
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   7.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   75.19
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.13.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.7f2
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.1.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.1.7f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.5
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.3d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    635.4.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.2b4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   615.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 214.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   214.0.0
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.8
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  237.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.1.7f2
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.7f2
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.2fc7
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 74.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.1.7f2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.4.1d13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.1.6
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  623.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  621.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 630.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.9.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   530.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 635.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,3, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.70f6
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D314131333333433920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.7f2 12718, 3 service, 21 devices, 3 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS256C, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 6
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: DMI External HDD, 0x0c0b  (Dura Micro, Inc.), 0x0336, 0xfd120000 / 5
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd130000 / 4
USB Device: Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000, 0x045e  (Microsoft Corporation), 0x00dd, 0xfd133000 / 7
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2640, 0xfd131000 / 6
USB Device: Ultra Fast Media Reader, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x4063, 0xfd131100 / 8
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: Typically, page faults are not caused by bad RAM (though it’s not 100% out of the question), but by software corruption of kernel data structures.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, assuming that the RAM was the only thing you changed (you didn't upgrade the OS or the HDD), and that the kernel panics didn't happen before the upgrade, that yes, the RAM is the culprit. It could be perfectly fine working RAM for a PC, but Macs are picky about their RAM, which can lead to problems including kernel panics.

Answer (score 0):

Since your drivers don't include any special one, it's possible from the RAM. If the RAM doesn't reliable, sometimes it will corruption of kernel data then cause these type of issue as well.  I had some experience with no stable RAM rather than fault RAM.